# Understand the rank of $ \begin{bmatrix} A&b\\ b^{*}&0 \end{bmatrix}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank

> Let $A \in M_n(C)$ and $b$ be a column vector of n complex complements. Denote $\widetilde A = \begin{bmatrix}
> A&b\\
> b^{*}&0 
> \end{bmatrix} $ If $rank(\widetilde A)=rank(A)$, which of the following is true?
>
> (a) $Ax = b$ has infinitely many solutions.
>
> (b) $Ax = b$ has a unique solution.
>
> (c)  $\widetilde Ax = 0$ has only solution x = 0.
>
> (d)  $\widetilde Ax = 0$ has nonzero solutions.
>
> Zhang, Fuzhen. Linear Algebra

I am assuming that $b^*$ is the conjugate transpose. Could you help me construct an example $A$ and $\widetilde A$ such as $rank(\widetilde A)=rank(A)$ ? I have hard time doing that without assuming that $b=0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one example:
 $$ \tilde A = \begin{pmatrix} -1 & 0 & -1 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \\ -1 & 1& 0 \end{pmatrix} $$

Comment: Thank you so much. Exactly what I am looking for :)

Answer (score 2):

Hint: If both matrices have the same rank (column rank = row rank), then $b$ lies in the column space of $A$ and so there is a linear combination of the columns of $A$ which gives $b$.

Comment: Could you please construct a simple example $A$ , $b$ and $\widetilde A$? That's where I am struggling.

Comment: For a trivial example, take $A=I, or $b=0$.

Comment: Is it ever possible for b not be $0$?

Comment: By the rank condition, yes its possible.

Comment: @Wuestenfux: That condition is not sufficient, because the same linear combination might not work for the last row of $\tilde A$.